# Does a javascript subclass need to have the same arguments as its parent?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, ecmascript-6, subclass

Here is my parent class:

```
class Parent {
  constructor(id, label, header="") {
    this.id = id;
    this.label = label;
    this.header = header;
  }
}
```

You can set the header manually if you like, and it will default to `""`.

For some child class however I want to disallow header being set at instantiation. Will this work:

```
class Child extends Parent {
  constructor(id, label) {
    super(id, label);
    this.header = "Default Header";
  }
}
```

That is, can the constructor of a child class omit some of the arguments of its parent?

Comment: You're ignoring the `header` variable in the parent class. Is that a typo or intended? (i.e you're not doing `this.header = header` and instead ignore it)

Comment: @svenskkunganka typo, cheers

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: That sounds more like `implements`, `extend` doesn't have such a thing. Child classes usually masks some arguments of the more general parent class as it becomes more specific.

Comment: @torazaburo Because I know that it will "work" in a toy script, because it's javascript so everything "works", but it may not be best practice/cause me troubles down the line.

Comment: @sabithpocker Probably my cause for concern is that a language like C# would not allow this - right?

Comment: I dont know `C#`. But such requirements arise from Liskov's Substitution Principle to be able to interchange parent/child instances without a trouble. This but doesnt apply for constructors and only for member function signatures.

Comment: @sabithpocker Awesome - SOLID seems to be where I've gotten this idea, and I'm less interested in if it works (in js) than if it's a good idea.

Comment: Your question says "can" and "need". If you meant "should" (in the sense of best practices), then say that. By the way, classes do not have arguments; their constructors do.

Comment: Well looks like I can skip writing an answer. Also look into factory pattern that comes handy when you want classes with different constructor params to be generated from a common place. SO doesnt entertain questions related to Best Practices and Software Design. softwareengineering.stackexchange might be a better place.

Answer (score 1):

No need for that. That's how class extending works. You are passing `parent` attributes to `child` class. As for `constructor` it's up to you what do you want to put there.

Comment: `class Child extends Parent` - Child class gets Parent attributes, not other way, right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it.

You can also invoke parents constructor (with 3 arguments) in child constructor:

```
class Child extends Parent {
  constructor(id, label) {
    super(id, label, "Default header");
  }
}
```